# Android Studio Multiple dex files define Lcom/abc/xyz/BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i am newbie to Android Studio, every time when try to Run my app, face the exception

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':abc:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/nik/Installs/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/nik/workspace/androidstudio/abc/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/nik/workspace/androidstudio/abc/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt


Error Code:
2


Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/abc/xyz/BuildConfig;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

try lot of solution like delete BuildConfig file etc but without luck. After lot of googling i just understand, problem related to multiple dependencies file but unable to solve.

Also try command 
gradle -q dependencies 
but fail with this error

FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.

- What went wrong:
  Build aborted because of an unexpected internal error. Please file an issue at: http://forums.gradle.org.

Also i like to mention i am try to migrate my project from eclipse and its build successfully when run Build->Rebuild Project in Android Studio

boxAndroidLibraryV2

```
dependencies {


compile project(':boxJavaLibraryV2')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2-1.0.0.jar')
}
```

boxJavaLibraryV2

```
dependencies {


compile files('libs/cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/easymock-3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/junit-4.8.2.jar')
compile files('libs/powermock-easymock-1.4.12-full.jar')
compile files('libs/robolectric-1.2-20121030.213744-165-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

mylib

```
dependencies {


compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
}
```

myApp

```
dependencies {


compile project(':boxAndroidLibraryV2')
compile project(':liveSdk')
compile project(':mylib')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev70-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/icu4j-4.8.1.jar')
compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.59.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')

}
```

i know some dependencies are multiple in box library like

compile files('libs/commons-io-2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')

but if i am try to remove these than face exception

```
Error:(6, 29) error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
Error:(80, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable IOUtils
Error:(6, 32) error: cannot find symbol class CharEncoding
Error:(57, 75) error: cannot find symbol variable CharEncoding
Error:(58, 79) error: cannot find symbol variable CharEncoding etc...
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: The `multiple dex files define...` error usually means that you have duplicate libraries in your build path. Could you share your project dependencies with us?

Comment: Thanks for reply George D. Now you can check the dependencies

Comment: `compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')`
`compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')`
could be one of those libraries conflicting, could you try commenting them out one by one?

Comment: comment compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar') lib and rebuild successfully but not able to run app, face same exception.

Comment: at last 
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Comment: Did you figure it out? Keep in mind that when you encounter problems like this there is a big chance it's a dependency problem.

Comment: @nikhil if your problem is solved, please answer it in a real answer not your own question. SO encourage to answer it's own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after lot of trials

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

this worked for me..